# Simple Regex help

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I have a format of 0000.00 that a number must fit.

If I receive 1, 12, 123, 1234, 1.23, 12.34, 123.45, 1234.56 I can accept them.  If they are in a different format eg. lengths are larger for instance or format is ABCDE then I need to reject them

Is there a Regex that will fit these formats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
^\d{1,4}(\.\d\d)?$
```

Captures 1 to 4 digits, then an optional `.` which must be followed by exactly two more digits (if it is present).

Comment: Regex.IsMatch("12346", @"\d{1,4}(\.\d\d)?
"); returns true which is wrong

Comment: You should add ^ and $ to the start and the end of your pattern, because your pattern returns true for 12345.67

Answer (score 0):

With trailing periods:

```
\d{0,4}(?:\.\d{0,2})?
```

Without trailing periods:

```
\d{0,4}(?:\.\d{1,2})?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d{1,4}(\.\d{1,2})?$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Cobbling together the other answers

```
^\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

1 to 4 digits which is optionally followed by a decimal places and 1 or 2 digits. The group is excluded from matches to improve performance.